# Custom button override in Salesforce

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce

I want to create a custom button override in Salesforce. I'd like to override the delete button so that instead of deleting, I just want it to change the record type.

My custom object is `Absence__c`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You only have to **edit** the **Page Layout**, **remove** the "*delete*" button,
Then create a **custom button** named "delete", set the javascript to button's behavior. Finally add that button to the page layout.

This is an example code for the custom button:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js")}

var AbsenceUpdate = new sforce.SObject("Absence__c");

AbsenceUpdate.Id='{! Absence__c.Id  }';
AbsenceUpdate.RecordTypeId = '{new record type id}';

if(AbsenceUpdate!=null)
{
    try
    {
     updateOpp = sforce.connection.update([AbsenceUpdate]);
      window.location.reload();
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert('error : ' + e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is a controller extension and an override of the existing Delete button.

```
<apex:Page action="changeRTRedirect"
    standardController="Absence__c" extensions="DeleteOverrideExtension">
</apex:page>

public class DeleteOverrideExtension {
    private SObject record;

    public DeleteOverrideExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        record = controller.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference changeRTRedirect() {
        record.RecordTypeId = '[YOUR NEW RT ID]';
        update record;
        //where do you want to send users now, maybe the Absence__c tab?
        return Page.MyPageHere;
    }
}
```